# Conditional formatting with AND condition in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to apply `AND` condition to conditional formatting in  openpyxl. Unfortunately it does not work, I try with FormulaRule:

```
sheet.conditional_formatting.add('P2:BA2', FormulaRule(formula=['AND(P2>0;BB2>0)'], fill=fill_red))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `'AND(P2>0,BB2>0)'`?

Comment: when I try 'AND' inside excel it states that ; is used, but i will try

Comment: You must use English semantics for all Excel formulae so I suspect the `;` should be `,`. If in doubt look at the source for the relevant worksheet.